# How to "Redirect to" after 'x' seconds using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs

I'm beginner in React Js. I would like to redirect to path '/event' after 2 seconds.

This way is not working:

```
import React from 'react';
import { getFormData } from '../../../helpers/form';
import { eventCreate } from '../../../actions/EventActions';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

if (event) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return <Redirect to={'/event'} />;
  }, 2000);
}
```

But if I change it to:

```
if (event) {
  return <Redirect to={'/event'} />;
}
```

It works perfectly. How could I redirect after 2 seconds?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**2022 Update**: While updating versions (React 18, React Router DOM 6) I noticed it required a bit of refactor.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function myComponent () {
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigate('/event')
    }, 2000)
  }, [])
  return <div>Content</div>
}
```

**2021 Update**: After learning more about React, I'd probably recommend using useEffect to mimic the functionality of componentDidMount in a functional component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useHistory } from 'react'

export default function myComponent () {
  const history = useHistory()

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      history.push('/event')
    }, 2000)
  }, [])
  return <div>Content</div>
}
```

**Previous answer**: Is your `if (event) {` inside a component of some sort? I think you could achieve this one of two ways. Either:

```
componentDidMount() {
  if (event) {
    setTimeout(() => { 
      this.props.history.push('/event');
    }, 2000)
  }
}
```

Note, to use componentDidMount and `this`, you'll have to use a class component which I don't see in your example. Or:

```
class RedirectExample extends Component {
  state = {
    redirect: false
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.id = setTimeout(() => this.setState({ redirect: true }), 2000)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearTimeout(this.id)
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.redirect
      ? <Redirect to='/event' />
      : <div>Content</div>
  }
}
```

As requested in a comment, I modified this answer to include a refactor to functional component. Note, the following code is untested but should give you an idea of how you might accomplish it.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'

function RedirectExample() {
  const [redirectNow, setRedirectNow] = useState(false)
  if (redirectNow) {
    return <Redirect to='/event' />
  }
  return <div>Content</div>
}
```

Or possibly (I haven't used useHistory before but from the documentation you might be able to do something like this):

```
import React from 'react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

function RedirectExample() {
  const history = useHistory()

  // setTimeout may cause an error
  setTimeout(() => {
    history.push('/event')
  }, 2000)
  return <div>Content</div>
}
```

Comment: I could refactor those to functional components if you'd prefer. Just let me know.

Comment: If its possible, refactor to functional component please. Thank you.

Comment: history object will not be readily available. consider wrapping the component in, for example, withRouter

Comment: Yeah, you'll have to set up history to use history. I'm just brain dumping what I've seen before to give y'all an idea of possibilities. I've updated my answer with functional components but note, they may require more work (e.g. setting up history) and they are untested.

Comment: Using { useHistory } and history.push I got what I've expected. Thank you sooo much by your help :D

Comment: where is the timeout or wait time setting in the `useState` answer?

Comment: @uberrebu After learning more React over the last year I probably would do it differently now but you could use the `useEffect` hook to mimic the `componentDidMount` functionality to `setTimeout` which I don't think would require `useState`. Again I haven't tested it but conceptually it should be possible.

Comment: yup that is what i went with..useeffect..already for react hooks for most of my stuffs..so went with useeffect

Comment: Thank you for the 2022 update - I was stuck and ready to post my own question! Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

In Functional Component you can use useHistory() hook of React like the previous mentioned and it will work but in Class based component you may not be able to do the same thing using Hook. So, if you want to perform the task you can use a little trick by taking an extra state just like this:

```
 this.state={
    redirect: false
 }


if (event) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({
       redirect: true
  }, 2000);
}

 render(){
  
    if(this.state.redirect){
       return <Redirect to='/event'/>
     }
 }
```

This may helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function SplashScreen() {
  const [redirectNow, setRedirectNow] = useState(false);
  setTimeout(() => setRedirectNow(true), 2000);
  return redirectNow ? (
    <Redirect to="/game" />
  ) : (
    <div className="SplashScreen">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SplashScreen;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const RedirectComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(2);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      // update the state after 1000ms
      setCount((currentCount) => currentCount - 1);
    }, 1000);
    // when count is 0, navigate
    count === 0 && navigate("/event");
    // clean up the interval
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [count, navigate]);
  return (
    <div>
          <p>Redirecting you in {count} sec </p>
    </div>
  );
};
```